# Can we fetch other app's data using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am building an app using Google Drive API and store data in the user's appdata space in the user's Google Drive. This way we can store data to avoid user accidentally delete since it's hidden from the user's view https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata

Question: can other apps (maybe even hacker) using the same API and pretend to be our app to fetch the our app data?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation found on [Store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata) . You will find it states.

> This folder is only accessible by your application and its contents are hidden from the user and from other Drive apps.

Only your app or rather your client id can access the files that it created.